# MYSQL Trigger - Using SUM with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum

I have two tables:
A `week` table with columns `week`,`Team_Number`, and `Points`.
A `Teams` table with columns `Team_Number` and `Session1Points`.
I'd like  to `sum` all of the `Points` from the `week` table where `week` column is between 1 and 9, then add that to the `Teams` table in the `Session1Points` column.

I've tried:

```
UPDATE Teams P
SET Session1Points =
(SELECT SUM(Points) from week
where week.Team_Number= P.Team_Number) 
where P.Team_Number = New.Team_Number
```

that's not working. I'd like it to trigger after I update the `week` table. Do I need to `Join` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JOIN this way

```
UPDATE Teams P
INNER Join (SELECT 
          Team_Number
        , SUM(Points)  as team_sum 
      from week
      group by Team_Number ) t on t.Team_Number=P.Team_Number 
SET Session1Points = t.team_sum
```

Comment: that's it, thanks @scaisEdge, just a note you have an extra s in Session1Points

Comment: @mcadamsjustin   . i removed the Ssession  extra s but i have copied the column name from your code .. ..answer updated ..